# Delete and Edit button on new line in a single column

Tags: c#, html, css, gridview, webforms

I am trying to add edit, delete button on my gridview using,

```
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit/Delete" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

however it looks like this now,

[image]

I want Delete button on a new row, what can I do ?

like this

> Edit 
>   Delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
first convert commandbuttons to template then
adding `<br />` between edit button and delete button

UPDATE In Gridview Task then Select the commands that you want to convert to TemplateField in "Selected Fields:" then check your source code. You will see in the ItemTemplate

> ```
>     <asp:ItemTemplate>
>         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
>                                 CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
>               <br />
>         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
>                                 CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
>     </ItemTemplate>
> ```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Just select this answer if this helps you.

Comment: no. I'm not telling you to copy my code it's just an example. You should try it on your own i'm only giving you an example.

Comment: No. I think you didn't get my example. But then, you should wait for others to answer your question. Have a nice day

Comment: try to decrease width of CommandField. It will be in new line.

Comment: Actually, @CarloAdap is on the right track. You can find more info here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1398155.aspx/1 The template allows you to control the look of your column (for example, you can use images)

Comment: I am not going to work on this project anymore for time being